# Adding a checkbox in React when input is declared void

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs

This is my problem, I have a list being rendered and returned as seen below:

```
return (
        <li className="itemsInList">{this.props.children}</li>
    )
```

but I want to add a checkbox so if I do this:

```
return (
        <input type="checkbox" className="itemsInList">{this.props.children}</input>
    )
```

but then an error is displayed: `arning: input is a void element tag and must not have children`

how can I get around this error to display them in a list with a checkbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the error is pretty clear. An input is not allowed to have children. This is part of the HTML definition. See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4)

I'm guessing that you want a checkbox for each of the items in `this.props.children`. 
So what I'd do is to keep the `<li>` and put the `<input>` inside.

```
return (
  <ul className="itemsInList">
    {this.props.children.map(function(child) { 
      return (<li className='child'>
        <input type='checkbox'>
        <label>{child.someAttribute}</label>
      </li>);
    }} 
  </ul>
);
```

Note that you will have to specify a unique `key` attribute to each of the `<li>` inside the loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this possible for radio input types (one choice vs multiple)

Comment: @ste_irl Yes, definitely. If you want 'one choice' you can just add a `name` attribute to the input, the same for all inputs, to create a group.